# Prove that the set {→, ¬} is functionally complete

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am not sure how to do this question. I have looked at some of the other similar questions but to no avail

I know that for a set of operators to be functionally complete, the set can be used to express all possible truth tables by combining members of the set into a Boolean expression

Comment: Do you know of another functionally complete set? Can you build equivalents to all the operations there with $\to$ and $\lnot$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implication $\to$ is defined by
$$ a\to b \equiv \neg a \vee b. $$

This means, that
$$ \neg a \to b \equiv a \vee b$$
and thus, you can express logical or using $\to$ and $\neg$. Furthermore you know de Morgans rules and you have
$$ \neg(\neg a \vee \neg b) \equiv \neg\neg a\wedge \neg\neg b = a\wedge b.$$

Thus you can express all logical operators using $\to$ and $\neg$. The set of these is known to be functionally complete.

Comment: what about the functional completeness of {∨, ¬}? Would this be proven in the same manner?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a hint on how to start the proof for that?

Comment: You can very easily get $\to$ using its definition and for $\wedge$ you can do the same trick as I did in my answer.

Comment: Why would you need to get $\to$? The set I am referring to is {∨, ¬}

Comment: In my answer we constructed $\vee$ and $\wedge$ from $\neg$ and $\to$. If you start with $\vee$ and $\neg$, you have to construct $\to$ and $\wedge$.

Comment: What if I want to prove it in terms of the functionally complete set  {∨, & , ¬}?

Comment: Also, I was looking at the operator $\to$ and was wondering if a set consisting of that operator only is functionally complete too?

Answer (score 2):

No,  $\to$ alone is not complete because you cannot get to negation, for example.